# Kendo MVVM data-value-update on multiple events

Tags: data-binding, kendo-mvvm

By default [kendo bind](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/value) its data on `change event`, we can change it on keyup using `data-value-update="keyup"`.

But i need both. I want to bind data on `keyup` and on `change`. I have tried it, by adding two events together like `data-value-update="change, keyup"`, unfortunately it is not working.

```
<textarea cols="20" data-bind="value:Comment" data-value-update="change, keyup" id="Comment" name="Comment" rows="2"></textarea>
```

Can anybody knows, is there any way to bind data in multiple events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this dojo will help you with what you are looking for:

https://dojo.telerik.com/ilaJurol

I have used the data-bind events collection to bind a keyup and change event.

This simple example just shows you the functions being triggered in a second textarea box showing you it has fired off the corresponding function.

Here is the example (control binding and viewmodel) that I created for this example:

**control**

```
<textarea cols="40" data-bind="value:Comment, events:{change: events.change, keyup: events.keyup}"  id="Comment" name="Comment" rows="40"></textarea>
```

**view model**

```
var vm = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
      Comment: 'I am a comment', 
      log: '', 
      events:{
        keyup:function(e){

          var that = this; 
          that.set('log', that.get('log') + '\r\nI have pressed the keyup button');

        }, 
        change:function(e){
          var that = this; 
                    that.set('log', that.get('log') + '\r\nI have triggered the change event');

        }
      }
    });
```

***UPDATE***

added updated dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/ilaJurol/7 based on comments.

Comment: I have changed your dojo code and created [this link](https://dojo.telerik.com/ilaJurol/2). Here i added a div for better understanding. When you delete character by pressing BackSpace, it doesn't immediately change text in div. But when you click outside of textarea, you will see div text has changed. That means data-value-update happens only changed event.

Comment: here is a modified version which updates the value after pressing a key. https://dojo.telerik.com/ilaJurol/3 I have added a console statement so you can see what is happening in the window. I am simply adding the key value to the end of the current "viewmodel" value and then setting that.

Comment: OK. I got your point, it triggers both event. But how can i update div text as soon as i delete a character from textarea. If i use this `this.set('Comment', e.data.Comments); ` in keyup event function it doesn't work.

Comment: here is another updated one showing you how to handle the backspace: https://dojo.telerik.com/ilaJurol/6 the question I have is why do you want to keep updating the value while someone is typing? Why isn't the change event enough for you as surely you only want to monitor the `state` of the value after someone has completed their typing? Obviously you will have to add additional case statements for other special key presses so that they are ignored.

Comment: Good question. why do you want to keep updating the value while someone is typing? Because if someone typing something in comments box(textarea) then directly click on save button (without clicking outside). In this situation textarea change event fired and focus move on save button but save button click event doesn't triggered.

Comment: https://dojo.telerik.com/ilaJurol/7 shows you how to do this without any events tagged to the comments box and it updates the div with the data on saving.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187934/discussion-between-arif-and-david-shorthose).

Comment: I have tested the dojo in IE 11 on windows 8.1 and 10 and in edge and it is working the same in chrome on both os. Please either update the question with the additional questions or provide a new question for the different problem.